# SharePoint Document's Library metadata duplicates after REST call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, ajax, typescript

I am making a POST ajax request to a SharePoint Document Library folder to save a file along with some metadata. The file and the metadata are saved correctly however, the metadata are sometimes(not all the time) replicated inside the document library(where I place folder not files). **Why does this happen?** ***How can I prevent this from happening?*** Here is a code snippet of the ajax call:

```
    var result = $.ajax(
          {
             url: siteUrl.concat("/lists/getbytitle('")
            .concat("Document Library Name")
            .concat("')/RootFolder/folders('")
            .concat("Folder Name")
            .concat("')/files/add(url = '").concat(fileName).concat("', overwrite = true)"),
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            headers: {
              "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
            },
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
            },
            async: false
          });
```

[image]

Comment: Hi David. Can you explain what it means, please? "metadata are sometimes replicated inside the document library" I don't think I follow

Comment: Thanks @DenisMolodtsov, each file comes with some data(metadata) such as the title, comments and so on. All that data is inside the correct folder however it sometimes find itself in the Document Library.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of an issue? I still don't understand what " it sometimes find itself in the Document Library." means

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov, I am not able to post pictures here for some reasons. I have a document library called Test Documents, inside the Test Documents library I have a set of folders for my projects(one folder per project). Inside every project folder I have a set of files. Each file has metadata(title, version, project number ...). I save a file called Test1.docx inside the Project 1 folder. Then I have code to save the metadata pertaining to that file inside the Project 1 folder, it works fine. However when I go in the Test Document library the Test1.docx metadata is there for a random folder.